# TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases FloatLayout, ConnectPage

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, kivy, multiple-inheritance

This Python-Kivy code is using multiple inheritance. I'm getting the above mentioned error. I want my InfoPage class to inherit all FloatLayout functions and initialization, and i want it to inherit the get_email function from the ConnectPage class. How should I sort this out?

```
class ConnectPage(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ConnectPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ----some code ----

    def get_email(self):
        return email

class InfoPage(FloatLayout, ConnectPage):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InfoPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        ---- some code ----

    def get_peers(self):
        peers = db.common_choices(self.get_email())
        return peers
```

Comment: Since FloatLayout is ConnectPage, why not extend only FloatLayout and override get_email to use the correct parent?

Comment: Since `ConnectPage` extends `FloatLayout`, you don't need to extend `FloatLayout` again in `InfoPage`. Try `class InfoPage(ConnectPage):`.

Comment: Doing that will run the __init__ method of ConnectPage (which I don’t want).. how to avoid that?

Comment: Or is there any other way to acces that get_email function? I want to use it in the InfoPage class